# A little animation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

I am new to javascript. I am trying to create a little animation. I have a background image and I have positioned an image exactly where I want it on that background image (lets call this image 'Princess'.

What I want is for Princess to move to a certain point in the background (according to pixel x & y values).

So far with the code below, Princess moves, but doesn't stop. I've come across the clearTimeOut() function while trying to find the solution,however, is there a way to stop the movement at a certain pixel point?

Here is the code I have so far. Thank you in advance :)

```
var imgObj = null;

function init(){
imgObj = document.getElementById('princess');
imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
moveRight();
}


function moveRight(){
imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
timer = setTimeout(moveRight, 150);
}


window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
function moveRight(){
imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
timer = setInterval(moveRight, 150);
if(parseInt(imgObj.style.left) > 100){
clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Use setInterval and clearInterval instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check in function `moveRight` and clearTimeout like bellow

```
function moveRight(){
    imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
    timer = setInterval(moveRight, 150);
    if(imgObj.style.left === '50px'){
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
```

I think  [*setInterval*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) & [*clearInterval*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval) matches to the requirement best.

Like bellow

```
<script>
    var imgObj = null;
    var interval;

        function init(){
        imgObj = document.getElementById('princess');
        imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
        imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
        interval = setInterval(moveRight, 150);
        }


        function moveRight(){
        imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
        if(imgObj.style.left === '50px')
            clearInterval(interval)
        }
        window.onload = init;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `setInterval` is better suited for that, also, `moveRight` doesn't suggest that it will stop at a given position.

For the condition part, you need to compare the actual position with a given limit.

Maybe something like this will be easier to maintain. Try this:

```
var DX=10;
var DELAY_MS=150;

function moveRightTo(limitX) {
    move(DX,0); // move X by 10
    var x = setInterval(function(){
        var posX = parseInt(imgObj.style.left);
        if (posX < limitX)
            move(DX,0);
        else
            clearInterval(x);
    }, DELAY_MS);
}

function move(x, y) {
    var posX = parseInt(imgObj.style.left);
    imgObj.style.left = (posX+x) + "px";

    // var posY = parseInt(imgObj.style.top);
    // imgObj.style.top = (posY+y) + "px";
}
```

Usage:

```
function init() {
    // ...
    moveRightTo(150);
    // moveLeftTo(25) ?
    // moveDownTo(200) ?
}
```